# How to get XML to JSON transformer in MuleSoft AnyPoint Studio v7?

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am trying to create a web service sample where I am consuming a web service and I am getting output in XML format. I checked some tutorials and found that there is an inbuilt XML to JSON transformer in AnyPoint Studio v6 but I am not able to find the same in Mule 4 and AnyPoint Studio v7. Can anyone suggest what should I do? I don't want to use DataWeave currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mule 4, you're going to have to use DataWeave sooner or later. They got rid of all the "x to y" transformers in Mule 4 because DataWeave supports these transformations.

If your payload is in XML (or any other format, really) and you want to convert it to JSON, you can do this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

Comment: Thanks. If my `payload/output` is direct JSON then what needs to be done? I am new to MuleSoft so asking this question.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What is `payload/output`? What is "direct JSON"?

Comment: direct JSON means if my REST web service response is in JSON format only, then can I read it directly or need to use `DataWeave`?